# Generic Single Linked List with smart pointers follow up part 3

Tags: c++, linked-list, pointers

Okay, this will most likely be the last post I make for Singe Linked List unless significant revision is needed. This post following from [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/201340/generic-single-linked-list-with-smart-pointers-follow-up-part-2).

Shout out to @hoffmale for showing me the ways of the force.

Here is the header file:

```
#ifndef SINGLELINKEDLIST_h
#define SINGLELINKEDLIST_h



template <class T>
class SingleLinkedList {
private:

    struct Node {
        T data;
        std::unique_ptr<Node> next = nullptr;

        template<typename... Args, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<T, Args&&...>::value>>
        explicit Node(std::unique_ptr<Node>&& next, Args&&... args) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_constructible<T, Args&&...>::value)
            : data{ std::forward<Args>(args)... }, next{ std::move(next) } {}

        // disable if noncopyable<T> for cleaner error msgs
        explicit Node(const T& x, std::unique_ptr<Node>&& p = nullptr)
            : data(x)
            , next(std::move(p)) {}

        // disable if nonmovable<T> for cleaner error msgs
        explicit Node(T&& x, std::unique_ptr<Node>&& p = nullptr)
            : data(std::move(x))
            , next(std::move(p)) {}
    };
    std::unique_ptr<Node> head = nullptr;
    Node* tail = nullptr;

    void do_pop_front() {
        head = std::move(head->next);
    }


public:
    // Constructors
    SingleLinkedList() = default;                                           // empty constructor 
    SingleLinkedList(SingleLinkedList const &source);                       // copy constructor

                                                                            // Rule of 5
    SingleLinkedList(SingleLinkedList &&move) noexcept;                     // move constructor
    SingleLinkedList& operator=(SingleLinkedList &&move) noexcept;          // move assignment operator
    ~SingleLinkedList();

    // Overload operators
    SingleLinkedList& operator=(SingleLinkedList const &rhs);

    // Create an iterator class
    class iterator;
    iterator begin();
    iterator end();
    iterator before_begin();

    // Create const iterator class
    class const_iterator;
    const_iterator cbegin() const;
    const_iterator cend() const;
    const_iterator begin() const;
    const_iterator end() const;
    const_iterator before_begin() const;
    const_iterator cbefore_begin() const;

    // Memeber functions
    void swap(SingleLinkedList &other) noexcept;
    bool empty() const { return head.get() == nullptr; }
    int size() const;

    template<typename... Args>
    void emplace_back(Args&&... args);

    template<typename... Args>
    void emplace_front(Args&&... args);

    template<typename... Args>
    iterator emplace(const_iterator pos, Args&&... args);

    void push_front(const T &theData);
    void push_front(T &&theData);
    iterator insert_after(const_iterator pos, const T& theData);
    iterator insert_after(const_iterator pos, T&& theData);
    void clear();
    void pop_front();
    void pop_back();
    iterator erase_after(const_iterator pos);
    bool search(const T &x);



};

template <class T>
class SingleLinkedList<T>::iterator {
    Node* node = nullptr;
    bool before_begin = false;

public:
    friend class SingleLinkedList<T>;

    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
    using value_type = T;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using pointer = T * ;
    using reference = T & ;

    iterator(Node* node = nullptr, bool before = false) : node{ node }, before_begin{ before } {}

    bool operator!=(iterator other) const noexcept;
    bool operator==(iterator other) const noexcept;

    T& operator*() const { return node->data; }
    T& operator->() const { return &node->data; }

    iterator& operator++();
    iterator operator++(int);
};

template <class T>
class SingleLinkedList<T>::const_iterator {
    Node* node = nullptr;
    bool before_begin = false;

public:
    friend class SingleLinkedList<T>;

    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
    using value_type = T;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using pointer = const T * ;
    using reference = const T & ;

    const_iterator() = default;
    const_iterator(Node* node, bool before = false) : node{ node }, before_begin{ before } {}

    operator const_iterator() const noexcept { return const_iterator{ node }; }
    bool operator!=(const_iterator other) const noexcept;
    bool operator==(const_iterator other) const noexcept;

    const T& operator*() const { return node->data; }
    const T& operator->() const { return &node->data; }

    const_iterator& operator++();
    const_iterator operator++(int);
};


template <class T>
SingleLinkedList<T>::SingleLinkedList(SingleLinkedList<T> const &source) {
    for (Node* loop = source.head.get(); loop != nullptr; loop = loop->next.get()) {
        emplace_back(loop->data);
    }
}

template <class T>
SingleLinkedList<T>::SingleLinkedList(SingleLinkedList<T>&& move) noexcept {
    move.swap(*this);
}

template <class T>
SingleLinkedList<T>& SingleLinkedList<T>::operator=(SingleLinkedList<T> &&move) noexcept {
    move.swap(*this);
    return *this;
}

template <class T>
SingleLinkedList<T>::~SingleLinkedList() {
    clear();
}

template <class T>
void SingleLinkedList<T>::clear() {
    while (head) {
        do_pop_front();
    }
}

template <class T>
SingleLinkedList<T>& SingleLinkedList<T>::operator=(SingleLinkedList const &rhs) {
    SingleLinkedList copy{ rhs };
    swap(copy);
    return *this;
}

template <class T>
void SingleLinkedList<T>::swap(SingleLinkedList &other) noexcept {
    using std::swap;
    swap(head, other.head);
    swap(tail, other.tail);
}

template <class T>
int SingleLinkedList<T>::size() const {
    int size = 0;
    for (auto current = head.get(); current != nullptr; current = current->next.get()) {
        size++;
    }
    return size;
}


template <class T>
template <typename... Args>
void SingleLinkedList<T>::emplace_back(Args&&... args) {
    std::unique_ptr<Node> newnode = std::make_unique<Node>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

    if (!head) {
        head = std::move(newnode);
        tail = head.get();
    }

    else {
        tail->next = std::move(newnode);
        tail = tail->next.get();
    }
}

template <class T>
template <typename... Args>
typename SingleLinkedList<T>::iterator SingleLinkedList<T>::emplace(const_iterator pos, Args&&... args) {
    if (pos.before_begin) {
        emplace_front(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        return begin();
    }

    if (pos.node->next) {
        pos.node->next = std::make_unique<Node>(std::move(pos.node->next), std::forward<Args>(args)...);  // Creating a new node that has the old next pointer with the new value and assign it to the next pointer of the current node 
        return { pos.node->next.get() };
    }
}


template <class T>
template <typename... Args>
void SingleLinkedList<T>::emplace_front(Args&&... args) {
    head = std::make_unique<Node>(std::move(head), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    if (!tail) tail = head.get(); // update tail if list was empty before
}


template <class T>
void SingleLinkedList<T>::push_front(const T &theData) {
    std::unique_ptr<Node> newNode = std::make_unique<Node>(theData);
    newNode->next = std::move(head);
    head = std::move(newNode);

    if (!tail) {
        tail = head.get();
    }
}

template <class T>
void SingleLinkedList<T>::push_front(T &&theData) {
    std::unique_ptr<Node> newNode = std::make_unique<Node>(std::move(theData));
    newNode->next = std::move(head);
    head = std::move(newNode);

    if (!tail) {
        tail = head.get();
    }
}

template <class T>
typename SingleLinkedList<T>::iterator SingleLinkedList<T>::insert_after(const_iterator pos, const T& theData) {
    return emplace(pos, theData);
}

template <class T>
typename  SingleLinkedList<T>::iterator SingleLinkedList<T>::insert_after(const_iterator pos, T&& theData)
{
    return emplace(pos, std::move(theData));
}

template <class T>
void SingleLinkedList<T>::pop_front() {
    if (empty()) {
        throw std::out_of_range("List is Empty!!! Deletion is not possible.");
    }

    do_pop_front();
}

template <class T>
void SingleLinkedList<T>::pop_back() {
    if (!head) return;

    auto current = head.get();
    Node* previous = nullptr;

    while (current->next) {
        previous = current;
        current = current->next.get();
    }
    if (previous) {
        previous->next = nullptr;
    }
    else {
        head = nullptr;
    }
    tail = previous;
    previous->next = nullptr;
}

template <class T>
typename SingleLinkedList<T>::iterator SingleLinkedList<T>::erase_after(const_iterator pos) {
    if (pos.before_begin) {
        pop_front();
        return begin();
    }

    if (pos.node && pos.node->next) {
        pos.node->next = std::move(pos.node->next->next);
        return { pos.node->next.get() };
    }

    return end();
}

template <class T>
bool SingleLinkedList<T>::search(const T &x) {
    return std::find(begin(), end(), x) != end();
}

template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &str, SingleLinkedList<T>& list) {
    for (auto const& item : list) {
        str << item << "\t";
    }
    return str;
}

// Iterator Implementaion////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <class T>
typename SingleLinkedList<T>::iterator& SingleLinkedList<T>::iterator::operator++() {
    if (before_begin) before_begin = false;
    else node = node->next.get();

    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
typename SingleLinkedList<T>::iterator SingleLinkedList<T>::iterator::operator++(int) {
    auto copy = *this;
    ++*this;
    return copy;
}

template<typename T>
bool SingleLinkedList<T>::iterator::operator==(iterator other) const noexcept {
    return node == other.node && before_begin == other.before_begin;
}

template<typename T>
bool SingleLinkedList<T>::iterator::operator!=(iterator other) const noexcept {
    return !(*this == other);
}



template<class T>
typename SingleLinkedList<T>::iterator SingleLinkedList<T>::begin() {
    return head.get();
}

template<class T>
typename SingleLinkedList<T>::iterator SingleLinkedList<T>::end() {
    return {};
}

template <class T>
typename SingleLinkedList<T>::iterator SingleLinkedList<T>::before_begin() {
    return { head.get(), true };
}

// Const Iterator Implementaion////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <class T>
typename SingleLinkedList<T>::const_iterator& SingleLinkedList<T>::const_iterator::operator++() {
    if (before_begin) before_begin = false;
    else node = node->next.get();

    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
typename SingleLinkedList<T>::const_iterator SingleLinkedList<T>::const_iterator::operator++(int) {
    auto copy = *this;
    ++*this;
    return copy;
}

template<typename T>
bool SingleLinkedList<T>::const_iterator::operator==(const_iterator other) const noexcept {
    return node == other.node && before_begin == other.before_begin;
}

template<typename T>
bool SingleLinkedList<T>::const_iterator::operator!=(const_iterator other) const noexcept {
    return !(*this == other);
}


template <class T>
typename SingleLinkedList<T>::const_iterator SingleLinkedList<T>::begin() const {
    return head.get();
}

template <class T>
typename SingleLinkedList<T>::const_iterator SingleLinkedList<T>::end() const {
    return {};
}

template <class T>
typename SingleLinkedList<T>::const_iterator SingleLinkedList<T>::cbegin() const {
    return begin();
}

template <class T>
typename SingleLinkedList<T>::const_iterator SingleLinkedList<T>::cend() const {
    return end();
}

template <class T>
typename SingleLinkedList<T>::const_iterator SingleLinkedList<T>::before_begin() const {
    return { head.get(), true };
}

template <class T>
typename SingleLinkedList<T>::const_iterator SingleLinkedList<T>::cbefore_begin() const {
    return before_begin();
}

#endif /* SingleLinkedList_h*/
```

Here is the main.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <random>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iosfwd>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <type_traits>
#include <ostream>
#include "SingleLinkedList.h"
#include "DoubleLinkedList.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {


    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////// Single Linked List //////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    SingleLinkedList<int> obj;
    obj.emplace_back(2);
    obj.emplace_back(4);
    obj.emplace_back(6);
    obj.emplace_back(8);
    obj.emplace_back(10);
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"---------------displaying all nodes---------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout << obj << "\n";


    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"----------------Inserting At Start----------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    obj.push_front(50);
    std::cout << obj << "\n";

    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"-------------inserting at particular--------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    obj.insert_after(obj.cbegin(),60);
    std::cout << obj << "\n";

    std::cout << "\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout << "-------------Get current size ---=--------------------";
    std::cout << "\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout << obj.size() << "\n";

    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"----------------deleting at start-----------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    obj.pop_front();
    std::cout << obj << "\n";

    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"----------------deleting at end-----------------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    obj.pop_back();
    std::cout << obj << "\n";


    std::cout<<"\n----------------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"--------------Deleting after particular position--------------";
    std::cout<<"\n-----------------------------------------------------------\n";
    obj.erase_after(obj.cend());
    std::cout << obj << "\n";

     obj.search(8) ? printf("yes"):printf("no");

     std::cout << "\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
     std::cout << "--------------Testing copy----------------------------";
     std::cout << "\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
     SingleLinkedList<int> obj1 = obj;
     std::cout << obj1 << "\n";


    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Nit: You've got your `operator const_iterator()` on the wrong class! I'm rather amazed that the compiler didn't warn about this. ...Ah, it's because the class is a template, so a lot of Clang's diagnostics (including this one) get suppressed.

Comment: @Quuxplusone Atually, clang does warn about it (and `emplace`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some nitpicks:

- Comments are still confusing/distracting
- `const_iterator::operator const_iterator()` should be moved to `iterator` instead (it doesn't make sense to convert a `const_iterator` to a `const_iterator`). Also, it should pass `before_begin` to the `const_iterator` constructor as well.
- Ther return types of `iterator::operator->()` should be `T*` instead of `T&`.
- Similarly, the return type of `const_iterator::operator->()` should be `const T*`.
- The destructor should be `noexcept`.
- While technically allowed, it might surprise users that the move assignment operator extends the lifetime of the elements originally contained in `*this`.
- `clear()` still doesn't update `tail`.
- `emplace` doesn't update `tail`.
- `emplace` has no value to return if both `if` conditions evaluate to `false`. Maybe throw an error message?
- There's code duplication in `push_front` and `emplace_front`. This could be fixed by having `push_front` call `emplace_front` internally.
- Inconsistent handling of an empty list in `pop_front` and `pop_back`: The former throws an exception, whereas the latter silently does nothing.
- I'm still not sure if `SingleLinkedList<T>::operator<<` needs to be part of `SingleLinkedList`. Since different users will have different opinions on the output format, they'll likely will write their own print functions anyways.

Comment: IIRC destructors are noexcept by default, since C++11