# Implementation of a Singularly LinkedList

Tags: c++, beginner, linked-list

I'm new to C++ and trying to learn by implementing data structures in it.

Is the code below the most efficient way of implementing the data structure in C++? Does it conform to C++ standards, and how readable is it?

```
#include <iostream>

class Node
{
public:
    int data;
    Node *next;
    Node(int data)
    {
        this->data = data;
        this->next = nullptr;
    }
};

class LinkedList
{
public:
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
    int length;
    LinkedList()
    {
        this->head = nullptr;
        this->tail = nullptr;
        this->length = 0;
    }

    void add(int data);
    void add(int data, int position);
    void delete_node(int position);
    int get_length();
    void print();
    int get_first();
};

void LinkedList::add(int data)
{
    Node *node = new Node(data);

    if (this->head == nullptr)
    {
        this->head = node;
    }
    else
    {
        this->tail->next = node;
    }
    this->tail = node;
    this->length = this->length + 1;
}

void LinkedList::add(int data, int position)
{
    Node *temp_head = this->head;
    Node *node = new Node(data);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < this->length)
    {
        if (i == position - 1)
        {
            node->next = this->head->next;
            this->head->next = node;
        }
        this->head = this->head->next;
        i++;
    }
    this->head = temp_head;
    this->length = this->length + 1;
}

void LinkedList::print()
{
    Node *temp_head = this->head;
    while (this->head != nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << this->head->data << '\n';
        this->head = this->head->next;
    }
    this->head = temp_head;
}

int LinkedList::get_length()
{
    return this->length;
}

int LinkedList::get_first()
{
    return this->head->data;
}

int main()
{
    LinkedList *llist = new LinkedList();
    llist->add(0);
    llist->add(1);
    llist->add(3);
    llist->add(4);
    llist->add(2, 2);
    llist->print();
    std::cout << "Length: " << llist->get_length() << '\n';
    std::cout << "First Element : " << llist->get_first() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: If you are new to a language, you should add the _beginner_ tag to your question. Reviewers take this tag into account.

Comment: Have a look at: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/125955/my-first-implementation-of-a-linked-list-in-c and my follow up. That should give you some hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the above, these are my comments:

### API completeness

One of the attractive features of a linked list is adding elements in O(1) anywhere in the list, given a Node*. But this API only allows for adding new elements in the middle in O(n) via add(int, position). I would at least allow a method of adding after a node, given a Node*.

### Encapsulation

Usually you don't want classes to have public members (one exception is static constexpr). So move head, tail and length to private.

### Code compactness

1. You don't need the constructor, because you can initialize the members using {} in their declaration. [prefer {}](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es23-prefer-the--initializer-syntax)
2. Conceptually, add(int data) is a private case of add(int data, int position), so the code should reflect that IMO.

### Readability

1. Since the length cannot be negative, it's better to use size_t instead of int.
2. Const correctness. Add the const specifier at the end of functions that don't change the list, like: getters, print() etc: `int get_length() const;`. Note that this would prevent changing head in print() - which is good because you don't expect the list to change if you're merely printing it.
3. Use the shorter `length += 1;` notation.

### Reusability

One big thing to remember when writing a container is to templatize it. Since you're now doing your first steps in C++ I understand that you want to take one step at time, so just int as the type is fine.

```
template<typename T>
class LinkedList
{
...
}
```

### Memory management

1. In add() use a self-managed std::shared_ptr instead of raw pointers and new. Read about smart pointers, they're one of the best features in C++11.
2. I don't see a reason for the `new LinkedList();` in main(). Just a `LinkedList list;` would be enough.

### Efficiency

In add(int data, int position), why continue traversing the while loop if you have already added the element?

### Unit tests

Testing is really important. I would suggest using a testing framework (I work with gtests) and writing some unit tests. Going through each public method and thinking how to test it -  by itself, or in conjunction with other functions - and writing unit tests to prove correctness is a sure way to increase quality.

Note that the implementation for delete_node() is missing. Make sure that it reuses the node search code that `add(data, position)` has.

Answer (score 4):

- C++ is not Java. You may safely get rid of all `this->`.
- The client doesn't need to know about `Node`. Make it an inner class of the `LinkedList`.
- The `~LinkedList()` destructor is missing. You should also consider (or prohibit) the copy constructor, `operator=`, and move constructor.
- `add(int data, int position)` may silently leak memory. If the `position` is too large, the created node is not linked into the list, and is lost. Also, there is no way to *prepend* a node.
- I don't like the `temp_head` approach. Better leave the `head` alone, and iterate using a cursor variable, e.g.:

  ```
  void LinkedList::print() {
      Node * cursor = head;
      while (cursor) {
          std::cout << cursor->data << '\n';
          cursor = cursor->next;
      }
  }
  ```

  At least, there is no need to restore `head`.

  Ditto for `add`.

Comment: That's a prime place for `for`: `void LinkedList::print() const { for (auto p = head; p; p = p->next) std::cout << p->data << '\n'; }`